# Regexp find groups in expression

Tags: regex, go

I have a code sample,

```
sliceArgument := args[1] // should look like e.g. `[1:5]` or `[:5]` or `[1:]`
expression := "^\\[(?P<first>\\d*?):(?P<last>\\d*?)\\]$"
r := regexp.MustCompile(expression)
r.FindStringSubmatch(sliceArgument)
startEndArgumentList := r.SubexpNames()
if len(startEndArgumentList)  >= 2 {
    argMap[`first`] = startEndArgumentList[0]
    argMap[`last`] = startEndArgumentList[1]
}
```

When I pass `[1:5]` as `args[1]` - I assume that [SubexpNames](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.SubexpNames) will give me values of two groups. Instead `SubexpNames` returns: `'', 'first', 'last'`.
What is wrong here?

Comment: what does `SubexpNames` return instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs says that the element of this array is always an empty string.

> `func (*Regexp) SubexpNames`
>
> `func (re *Regexp) SubexpNames() []string`
>
> SubexpNames returns the names of the parenthesized subexpressions in this Regexp. The name for the first sub-expression is names[1], so that if m is a match slice, the name for m[i] is SubexpNames()[i]. **Since the Regexp as a whole cannot be named, names[0] is always the empty string.** The slice should not be modified.

Take a look at the example from the docs:

```
func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?P<first>[a-zA-Z]+) (?P<last>[a-zA-Z]+)")
    fmt.Println(re.MatchString("Alan Turing"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.SubexpNames())
    reversed := fmt.Sprintf("${%s} ${%s}", re.SubexpNames()[2], re.SubexpNames()[1])
    fmt.Println(reversed)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("Alan Turing", reversed))
}
```

They use `re.SubexpNames()[2]` and `re.SubexpNames()[1]` as well (not `re.SubexpNames()[0]`).

Also: `SubexpNames` returns names of the groups, not matched values. To get the values, use `FindStringSubmatch`, see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483652/how-to-get-capturing-group-functionality-in-golang-regular-expressions) and in its [demo](https://play.golang.org/p/8LtH7lj1S7S).

Comment: may be I use wrong function, but I would like to get group values.

Comment: like `1` and `5` from `[1,5]`