# repeated, arbitrary capture groups

Tags: regex, go, re2

Given a string, eg.:

```
static_string.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.final_string
```

but with an arbitrary number of `label__value.` components, how can I repeat the capture groups, split them into label & value, and also capture the terminating final_string ?

For the above I'd want [`name`, `john`, `id`, `6`, `foo`, `bar`, `final_string`]

Is something like this possible when I don't know the number of `label__value.` components in advance?

This is for golang / RE2 if that matters.

Update: I don't have the luxury of doing this in a few lines of code, and would need to do this in a single regex. The regex is defined in a config file to an application I don't control, so a code based loop with conditionals etc is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: I'm not versed in Go this is fairly simple in java, you determine a capturing group and then loop through the results, so looking for similar stuff in go I found this, it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483652/how-to-get-capturing-group-functionality-in-golang-regular-expressions

Comment: When you say "arbitrary number of `label__value`" is there a maximum number of occurances?

Comment: @DeanTaylor yes, probably in the region of 10 ish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on what the thing you are putting this into expects.

This is answer focused on getting you the capture groups in a basic way attempting to avoid any issues with the "thing" you are putting the regex into and RE2.

Note: You might find that the `final_string` doesn't get the capture group index you expect with this method, but again depends on what you are putting the regex into.

A regular expression that would match "one" and "no" key/value pairs the following is:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+))$
```

- `static_string.final_string`
- `static_string.name__john.final_string`

---

To support one more key/value pair we repeat part of the regular expression:
Part repeated:

```
(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?
```

---

So to support 2 key value pairs the regular expression is:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+))$
```

This now supports the following additional example:

- `static_string.name__john.foo__bar.final_string`

---

So if I expand that out to support 12 key value pairs the regular expression is:

```
^[^.]+(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+?)__([^.]+))?(?:\.([^.]+))$
```

This supports the following additional examples:

- `static_string.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.final_string`
- `static_string.name2_1b__john.id__6.foo__bar.final_string`
- `static_string.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.name__john.id__6.foo__bar.final_string`

Comment: I hit accept as this gets me way closer to what I wanted, but are you aware of a way to implement exactly this with an unknown number of key__value pairs?

Comment: @DanielleM. I'm not, not without additional coding i.e. not just a regular expression.

Comment: @DanielleM. also don't feel the need to hit accept, you could leave it open perhaps someone else knows better than myself. Perhaps check back in another time.