# golang regex to find a string but only extract the substring within it

Tags: regex, go

I have a two strings like this

```
mystr = "xyz/10021abc/f123"
mystr2 = "abc/10021abd/c222"
```

I want to extract 10021abc and 10021abd. I came up with

```
r = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:xyz\/|abc\/)(.+)\/`)
```

But when I want to extract the match using this:

```
fmt.Println(r.FindString(mystr))
```

It returns the entire string. How should I change my regex?

Comment: You already have it, it is in the first capture group. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483652/how-to-get-capturing-group-functionality-in-go-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FindStringSubmatch`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp@go1.19.1#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch).

```golang
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:xyz\/|abc\/)(.+)\/`)
var s1 = "xyz/10021abc/f123"
var s2 = "abc/10021abd/c222"

fmt.Println(re.FindStringSubmatch(s1)[1])
fmt.Println(re.FindStringSubmatch(s2)[1])
```

https://go.dev/play/p/C93DbfzVv3a

Comment: This program crash when there is no match

Comment: Of course it does. Any Go slice index expression will crash if there isn't enough elements in the slice. The standard approach is to check the slice's length *before* indexing. But that was not your question.

Comment: I already know how to do this. My Q is how to change the regex

Comment: It is a regex skill Q rather than a go programming Q if that makes sense ;)

Comment: I am happy to take this answer if you think updating regex to just match the substring I need is too hard

Comment: @drdot Well your regex matches and captures the substring for the two input examples you've shown, only your method of retrieving the match was wrong. If your question is about how to use regex to match infinite number of variations of the general structure in the two input string then why not use something like the following? https://go.dev/play/p/CdsXlvKVMph

Comment: @drdot for completness sake: https://go.dev/play/p/ws7UfBD98nP

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am just curious if there a way to have only one matching group and match the middle string "10021abc" and not have two matching group?

Comment: @drdot I do not know if an RE can be written, using Go, that would match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```
var mystr = "xyz/10021abc/f123"
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*?/|/.*$`)
var output = re.ReplaceAllString(mystr, "")
fmt.Println(output)  // 10021abc
```